# Generate `insert` statements for each entry in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

What is the simplest way to generate `insert` statements fro every entry in a table? For a table with 3 rows, I need to generate 3 insert statements.

For a table with *n* rows I need to write to a file *n* `insert` statements.

For example, for row (foo, bar, baz) I need to write to that file the statement:

```
insert into desired_table values (foo, bar, baz)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html), use the `/*insert*/` "hint".

```
select /*insert*/ * from t1;

REM INSERTING into T1
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into T1 (C1,C2) values (1,2);
Insert into T1 (C1,C2) values (2,3);
Insert into T1 (C1,C2) values (3,4);
```

Another useful "hint":

```
select /*csv*/ * from t1;

"C1","C2"
1,2
2,3
3,4
```

Starting with version 4.1, the "hint" the below also works:

```
set sqlformat insert
select * from t1;
```

The output can be spooled as well:

```
set sqlformat insert
spool C:\Users\balaz\Desktop\insert.sql
select * from t1;
spool off
```

Run the above as a script (F5), and not a statement (Ctrl+Enter).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58761/discussion-between-cristid9-and-balazs-papp).

Comment: When I ran the command in SQL Developer and got the result in the Script output window it was limited to 5000 rows. When I spooled the output I got all rows.